# Selenium WD | How do I copy all values from a WebElement list into a String list?

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist

I have a list that I collecting a list of stock prices that are constantly changing

> List  listOfLastPrice1;

I know that this list is not constant as the price of stocks is not constant. Meaning if I print it now, and will print it again in 5 minutes, values would change. Why?  because this is a WebElement list that is connected to the DOM directly.

I have created a second list

> ArrayList listCopyLastPrice1 = new ArrayList();

I would like to copy all values from the WebElement list, into the String list.
How do I do that?

I tried several attempts but with no success

```
package TestMain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import PageObjects.Editions;

public class Test {

public void getList(WebDriver driver) {



driver.get("https:www.investing.com/Markets");
List <WebElement> listOfLastPrice1;
listOfLastPrice1= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-column-name='last'][class*='pid']")); 

ArrayList<String> listCopyLastPrice1 = new ArrayList<String>();

//..........

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `WebElement` list and add values to `String` list

```
List <WebElement> listOfLastPrice1;
listOfLastPrice1= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-column-name='last'][class*='pid']")); 

List<String> listCopyLastPrice1 = new ArrayList<String>();

for (WebElement element : listOfLastPrice1) {
    listCopyLastPrice1.add(element.getText());
}
```

EDIT:

Since Java 1.8 you can use `Stream` API to change the list of `WebElement`s to list of `String` like this:

```
List<String> listOfLastPrice1WithStrings = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-column-name='last'][class*='pid']"))
    .stream() 
    .map(x -> x.getText())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @dimaedunov Please, accept my answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Just did, sorry I'm new at this. Great and Easy-to-do solution

Comment: @dimaedunov Glad, I could help. Happy coding!

Comment: Of-coarse your answer is to the point without any side-talks (+1)

Comment: @DebanjanB I saw many of your posts and I think the side-talk is very useful. I read some of your answers and learned a thing or two, even tho, I am advanced. Keep doing what you do!

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can't copy a *List* of **WebElement** within a *List* of **String** type. Attempting that will raise [**`ClassCastException`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html). But you can store any of the attributes of the *WebElements* (e.g. id, name, innerText, innerHTML) within the **String** type *List* as follows :

```
List<String> listCopyLastPrice1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> listOfLastPrice1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-column-name='last'][class*='pid']"));
for(WebElement elem:listOfLastPrice1)
    listCopyLastPrice1.add(elem.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
System.out.println(listCopyLastPrice1);
```

Comment: It is possible, Please see the additional solution from  Rafał Laskowski

Comment: @dimaedunov DebanjanB's solution is very similar and it looks like it would also answer your question. +1